# How to create a nested action in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use blow URL for my delete and edit and detail of my product

> localhost:3891/Administrator/ShowProduct/delete/id?AdminId=12
>
> localhost:3891/Administrator/ShowProduct/Edit/id?AdminId=12
>
> localhost:3891/Administrator/ShowProduct/detail/id?AdminId=12

I tried blow code for RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Administrtor",
            url: "Administrator/ShowProduct/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Administrator", action = "ShowProduct", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );
```

My controller is Administrator and my action is ShowProduct

How I can create Another Action Subset of ShowProduct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Area in asp.net-mvc like this first right click on project name and go add and select Area and then right click on Area folder and Add Area, then type name of Area in my case :Administrator

every Area have model,view,controller

For Controller in my case : right click on controller folder and type this name 
ShowProduct

and now I can write any action for it like edit,delete and detail

Answer (score 1):

You can create Controller with the name Administrator with Delete, Edit and Details actions.

**Route Code**

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Administrtor",
        url: "Administrator/ShowProduct/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Administrator", action = "Delete", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
```

**Controller Code**

```
 public class AdministratorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Delete(int adminId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int adminid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Edit(int adminid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Generated URLs**

http://localhost:64922/Administrator/showproduct/Edit/1
http://localhost:64922/Administrator/showproduct/Details/1
http://localhost:64922/Administrator/showproduct/Delete/1

If you want to display adminId in URL (?adminId=) then change the adminId to Id in route.

Comment: But ShowProduct is action that contains list of my product and each item of this list contains edit and delete ...

Comment: Generally, in real-time web applications, we have a repository to maintain the list of product. Products may be either in Database or managed by some service. It's not the responsibility of the controller to manage the list of products instead Controller defines action methods to perform operations (e.g. Add, Edit, Delete, Details etc.) over the list of products. So you need to define Product list outside of the controller in some Repository class say ProductRepository.